# Cypress not able to locate element

Tags: cypress, locate

I am not able to find this element by using *cy.get('#cmpbox')*

```
<div id="cmpbox" class="cmpbox cmpstyleroot cmpbox3 cmpboxWelcomeGDPR" aria-modal="true" role="alertdialog" aria-labelledby="cmpboxheadline1" style="display: block; ....
```

It is a cookie box which pops up, I am also not able to select it by Cypress Selector. It is somehow ignoring it?

Comment: What is a purpose of that action? How about closing that popup with injecting cookies to the browser with `Cypress.Cookies`?

Comment: That is my actual problem, even if I cy.setCookie('xx', 'xx') I can't get rid off the cookie banner.